# Error In asp.net core AddDbContent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to asp.net core. I just encountered 2 errors in Asp.net core while practicing it. Here is the picture of the codes of 2 files.

[image]

**Error 1:**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0311  The type 'CRUD.AppDbContext' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method
>   'EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext(IServiceCollection,
>   Action, ServiceLifetime, ServiceLifetime)'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from 'CRUD.AppDbContext' to
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.    CRUD    C:\Users\mkshu\source\repos\CRUD\CRUD\Startup.cs    21  Active

Error 2:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1729  'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1
>   arguments CRUD    C:\Users\mkshu\source\repos\CRUD\CRUD\AppDbContext.cs   8   Active

Comment: make your AppDbContext inherits from DbContext : `public class AppDbContext : DbContext`

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. You can provide images if you think it helps clarify your question, but these should serve only a supporting role; your question should have everything necessary to answer it if images were to be removed.

Comment: itminus. Thank you. That was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right answer was commented by itminus

make your AppDbContext inherits from DbContext : public class AppDbContext : DbContext